# For an $[\![n,k,d]\!]$ degenerate stabilizer code, can product of two distinct correctable errors with same syndrome have weight less than $d$?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

For an $[\![n,k,d]\!]$ degenerate stabilizer code, let's say there exist two distinct correctable errors, $E_a$ and $E_b$, which have the same syndrome. Could there exist a case such that
$$ \text{Weight}(E_a E_b) < d \,, $$

i.e., two errors with the same syndrome acting together have weight less than $d$, where $E_a E_b$ is non-trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_a$ and $E_b$ be two correctable errors for some degnerate $[\![ n,k,d ]\!]$ stabilizer code $\mathcal{C}(S)$, where $\langle{S}\rangle$ are stabilzier generators.

Let $E_a \neq E_b$ and $\vec{s_a} = \vec{s_b}$ where  $\vec{s_a}$ & $\vec{s_b}$ are error syndromes corresponding to $E_a$ & $E_b$ respectively.

Therefore, $E_a E_b$ will always have syndrome $\vec{s_a} \oplus \vec{s_b} =\vec{s_a} \oplus \vec{s_a} = (0,0,\cdots,0)  \equiv (+1,+1,\cdots,+1)$.

(labelling $+1$ and $-1$ outcomes as $0$ and $1$, respectively.)

Therefore, $E_a E_b |{\overline{\psi}}\rangle$ lies in the codespace--where $|{\overline{\psi}}\rangle$ is a state in the codespace--as syndrome $(+1,+1,\cdots,+1)$ corresponds only to the codespace. Therefore, $E_a E_b \in N(S)$. Let's split the argument into two mutually exclusive and exhaustive cases.

##### Case 1 - $E_a E_b$ acts as logical identity operation on the codespace

- $E_a E_b \in S\,.$

Example of this case: Shor's code, where, for example, $E_a = Z_1 \,\,,E_b = Z_2$ and hence $E_a E_b = Z_1 Z_2$ have weight 2, which is less than $d$ for Shor's code, $d=3$.

This is a trivial case.

##### Case 2 - $E_a E_b$ acts as a non-trivial logical operation on the codespace

- $E_a E_b \notin S\,.$
- $E_a E_b \in N(S) \setminus S \,.$

Hence, $E_a E_b$ is a logical operation on $\mathcal{C}(S)$.

We know that, for every code with distance $d$, every element from $N(S)    \setminus S$ for a given $\mathcal{C}(S)$ will have weight greater than or equal to $d$.

Hence $\text{Weight}(E_a E_b) \geq d$ and it is not possible in Case$(2)$ such that $\text{Weight}(E_a E_b) < d$.

##### Fun Fact

You can conclude the following characterization for degenerate stabilizer codes from this-

| Lemma: |
| --- |
| An $ [\![n,k,d]\!]$ stabilizer code is degenerate if and only if the set of stabilizers $S$ contains an element with weight less than $d$, other than the identity operator. |