# For a degenerate quantum error correcting code, what can we conclude about product of two distinct correctable errors with same syndrome?

Tags: error-correction

It can be seen in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/35486/25170) that for a stabilizer code, the two distinct correctable errors with the same syndrome acting together is always a stabilizer.

However, what can we conclude in the case of non-additive quantum codes or subsystem codes or in a completely general case?

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the error channel with correctable errors for a given code $\mathcal{C}$ have Kraus operators $\{E_1, E_2, \cdots E_k\}\,.$

Then, the recovery operation for code $\mathcal{C}$ will be a recovery map $\mathcal{R}$ with Kraus operators $\{ U_1^\dagger P_1, U_2^\dagger P_2 , \cdots , U_l^\dagger P_l\}\,,$ which are the projective syndrome measurement followed by the correction
operation corresponding to syndrome outcome. Here, we think of the index $l$ from the outcome of the projective measurement. $l$ is the syndrome outcome.

However, I am not sure how to approach trying to conclude what will be the case, where two errors get the same $l^{\text{th}}$ outcome.

Let $E_a$ and $E_b$ be two distinct errors for a degenerate code with the same syndrome. Let's say recovery of error $E_a$ results in getting Kraus operator $U_a^\dagger P_a$ and recovery of error $E_b$ also results in getting Kraus operator $U_a^\dagger P_a\,.$ Then what can we conclude about $E_a E_b$?